# ambiguous column names when joining tables in dplyr using sqlite data source

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I love the joins in `dplyr`.  They work very smoothly, regardless of the datasource (local dataframe, remote database tables). **However, I have run into a problem, where the behavior of joins differs depending on the data source. I need a workaround for the problem described below.** I assume this is NOT a bug, but rather has to do with the backend being sqlite.

I can join the following tables very easily using dplyr.

```
observation <- data.frame(id=101:105, specimen_id=1:5, variable_id=1:5, value=rnorm(5))
specimen <- data.frame(id=1:5, specimen_name=LETTERS[1:5], species_id=1:5)
species <- data.frame(id=1:5, species_name=LETTERS[11:15])
variable <- data.frame(id=1:5, variable_name=LETTERS[6:10])

observation %>% 
  left_join(specimen, by=c("specimen_id"="id")) %>%
  left_join(species, by=c("species_id"="id")) %>%
  left_join(variable, by=c("variable_id"="id"))
```

Result is

```
   id specimen_id variable_id      value specimen_name species_id species_name variable_name
1 101           1           1 -0.6782149             A          1            K             F
2 102           2           2 -1.3226305             B          2            L             G
3 103           3           3 -0.2670939             C          3            M             H
4 104           4           4 -1.2546326             D          4            N             I
5 105           5           5 -1.1453585             E          5            O             J
```

**However, if I copy the same dataframes to a sqlite data source, the identical join code will fail.**

```
#create a database locally, and copy the dataframes
my_db <- src_sqlite("my_db.sqlite3", create = T)

copy_to(my_db, df=observation, temporary = FALSE)
copy_to(my_db, df=specimen, temporary = FALSE)
copy_to(my_db, df=species, temporary = FALSE)
copy_to(my_db, df=variable, temporary = FALSE)

#connect to those tables using dplyr
observation <- tbl(my_db, "observation")
specimen <- tbl(my_db, "specimen")
species <- tbl(my_db, "species")
variable <- tbl(my_db, "variable")
```

Now, the identical join code will fail.

```
observation %>% 
  left_join(specimen, by=c("specimen_id"="id")) %>%
  left_join(species, by=c("species_id"="id")) %>%
  left_join(variable, by=c("variable_id"="id"))
```

**Results in the following error:**

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement) : 
 error in statement: ambiguous column name: id.y
```

Comment: What is your "statement"? Does it contain a call to a column "id.y" that doesn't exist?

Comment: good question.  I don't know how to see the SQL that dplyr creates, but that could definitely help.

Comment: Yeah, with that error, I feel like it has something to do with the query it is making. I'm not familiar with the sqllite functions, but perhaps looking into the documentation or `traceback()` could help.

Comment: You can look at `observation %>% left_join(specimen, by=c("specimen_id"="id")) %>% explain()` to see what's happening with the joins that work. The SQL version is accumulating the "id" column not involved with the join.

Comment: on twitter, @hadley says this may be a bug.  I filed an [issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1458) on github